# Using Websocket and Socket io in React to connect to two different servers, getting multiple requests from socket io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, ws

I have a client that gets data from an existing WebSocket server via WS does stuff with the data and sends it to a separate personal server via Socket.io in which the personal server is built-in.

it works completely fine for the most part, however, I get multiple emits per request from the Socket.io server.

I put a print statement on the client whenever it gets something for the socket io server, and sometimes it prints out like 2-15 times per request, is this something to do with react, or is WS and socket io having problems coexisting?

it's causing a memory issue, as well as a 429 error at times.